# Collateral effects on banned IP on hMailServer?

Tags: hmail-server

In hMailServer:

I want to know what happens if I ban one or more IP addresses or domains.

Of course, the emails will not be accepted by hMailServer, but is the banned IP address marked as SPAM source?
Is there any other (global) impact on the source that is banned?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Again, I found my answer alone, asking this directly on hMailServer forum.

The answer is here: http://www.hmailserver.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=7&t=20364&p=123981#p123981